# do While loop not working for string comparing in C

Tags: c

I'm very new to C Programming so kindly bear with me . Below is my C language code . which according to my knowledge should work but when i enter "exit" then according to my logic it should work . which it ain't .Kindly let me what i'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

int main () {
char command[50];

do{
    int  pid ;
    char bin_dir[100]     ;
    char sbin_dir[100]    ;
    command[50] = '\0';    

    printf("\n get input to execute command: ");
    fgets (command, 100, stdin);

    printf("\n Entered command is : %s " ,command);

    strcpy(sbin_dir,"/sbin/");
    strcpy(bin_dir,"/bin/");

    strcat(bin_dir  ,command);
    strcat(sbin_dir ,command);

     if( access( bin_dir, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
         printf(" command found in bin Directory \n");
       } else if (access( sbin_dir, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
         printf(" command found in sbin Directory \n");
       }else {
         printf("command not found \n");
       }

    }while(strcmp (command, "exit") == 0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This site is not a debugger. Please learn to use one, and/or cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: `fgets (command, 100, stdin);` (char command[**50**];)--> `fgets (command, sizeof command, stdin);` and remove newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The loop must be `while (strcmp(...) != 0)`, not `== 0`.
2. I think `fgets` will read line with LF at the end - compare `strcmp(command,"exit\n")`.

PS: `command[50] = '\0'` is wrong. Must be `command[49] = 0` or better `memset(command, 0, sizeof command)`.

PS2: `fgets (command, 100, stdin)` has little problem - `command` is array of 50 bytes, and `fgets` allows up to 100. Use `fgets (command, sizeof command, stdin)`.

Comment: dear still not getting out of loop after entering `exit` - tried both `strcmp(command,"exit\n") != 0` and `strcmp(command,"exit") != 0`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi Put breakpoint after `fgets` and see values in `command` buffer.